# PHP / Mysql : Register isn't creating new users in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, registration

So I have two PHP files that are supposed to talk to eachother during User Registration.

The first: register.inc.php is supposed to create a new user in mysql database on MAMP and the second is register.php which is the basic form and is supposed to send it's data to register.inc.php.  I am not receiving any errors in either files but it does not want to both: create the user and redirect to the register-success.php page.

Any idea what is going on?

register.inc.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

//echo var_dump($_POST['username']);

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
                $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not work
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
```

register.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Registration Form</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Registration form to be output if the POST variables are not
        set or if the registration script caused an error. -->
        <h1>Register with us</h1>
        <?php
        if (!empty($error_msg)) {
            echo $error_msg;
        }
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li>Usernames may contain only digits, upper and lower case letters and underscores</li>
            <li>Emails must have a valid email format</li>
            <li>Passwords must be at least 6 characters long</li>
            <li>Passwords must contain
                <ul>
                    <li>At least one upper case letter (A..Z)</li>
                    <li>At least one lower case letter (a..z)</li>
                    <li>At least one number (0..9)</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Your password and confirmation must match exactly</li>
        </ul>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
                method="post" 
                name="registration_form">
            Username: <input type='text' 
                name='username' 
                id='username' /><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
            Password: <input type="password"
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/><br>
            Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br>
            <input type="button" 
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" /> 
        </form>
        <p>Return to the <a href="index.php">login page</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
```

But you do not have input in the form with name "p" -> $_POST['p']

so isset always return false

I suppose you wanted to type $_POST['password']

Comment: I have tried that, I was following a tutorial so I can better understand the syntax of PHP. The 'P' is calling a variable in my js file that checks if the p was filled out and whether it is long enough.

Comment: For the sake of trying everything, I changed them to the above and it still doesn't fire anything off, I'm completely dumbfounded.

Comment: ether you sould add the JavaScript code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the order of your **db_connect** and **psl-config**:

```
include_once 'psl-config.php';
include_once 'db_connect.php';
```